# Azure B2C custom policy calling a RESTfull provider from a DisplayControl error handling

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How does one handle failures when using a DisplayControl which calls the RESTfull provider during the "SendCode" action?

I.e. when the HTTP endpoint is unavailable and the user selects the send code button, then the flow just hangs with the "progress bar" icon displaying.

I've tried changing the ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile's "ContinueOnError" setting, but when setting it to true, it just skips to the next ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile. I've even added a boolean assert validation in the next validation, nothing happens.

The only way forward seems to be doing full "custom pages" using `<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneVerificationPage1">` as per the "phone-number-passwordless" sample...?

Further information:
When the RESTfull provider is called directly from a orchestration step the following expected error is returned:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the API is unavailable, we have a 30sec timeout, and retry 3 times, this is likely what you see as a hang. Once it comes back, you can configure errors as per this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#error-handling

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the behavior is different when using it in a DisplayControl, unless I'm doing something wrong there. I actually noticed another RESTfull provider works as expected in other areas, i.e. when not used in a DisplayControl